# Allow users to invoice for their work via stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on a merchant platform connecting my app users to clients. One of the features I'd like to add for convenience is to allow my users to invoice customers right there within the app.

I believe stripe is a good solution for something like this, but can't figure out correct workflow for this and which products of theirs to use. In essence I envision full workflow to be as follows

1. User agrees to create stripe account for my app
2. App either directs them to stripe or perhaps such account can be created via api?
3. User issues an invoice within the app with a link to stripe payments page
4. Client pays the invoice, app server gets some sort of webhook so we can process this
5. Funds will go directly to users stripe acc? So we don't need to worry about custody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is possible, but you would want to start with Stripe Connect's Doc first, especially to choose [**funds flow and Connected Account type**](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) between Destination Charge/Express or Custom, Direct Charge/Standard or Separate Charges and Transfers/Express or Custom.

Among them, Destination Charge with Express would be easiest. For step 1 and 2 you would want to [create and onboard Express account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts), and for step 3, 4, 5 you need to implement [the Destination Charge flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges). You should follow Stripe Doc for detailed explanation for fund flows and step-by-step integration.